# ASP.NET Load Control Problems Using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET page (Page A) that has some HTML and a single HTML control that loads a form (Control A). When I am finished saving the form in Control A, I want the HTML control in Page A to load the next control. I have been unable to make this work and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I am using in Control A to trigger the function in Page A to load the control.

```
    Protected Sub btnSave2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave2.Click
    Try
        Dim ctest As New frmMain
        ctest.NextButton()
    Catch ex As Exception
```

This is the function in Page A that is being fired, but not loading anything

```
    Public Sub NextButton()
    Dim cname As New Control
    cname = LoadControl("EP/ctlE1_01_03.ascx")
    Me.dvContent.Controls.Add(cname)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Virtual Path:

```
cname = LoadControl("~/EP/ctlE1_01_03.ascx")
```

Comment: No luck, I ran debug and produced an error stating "null reference exception was caught"

Comment: Might still work if your EP directory isn't one off the root. Where is it?

Comment: Root / EP is the directory where the control lives. Page A lives in the root.

Comment: try to load control in Page OnInit Event.

Comment: OP needs it to happen on click though if I read it correctly. OnInit won't do. Unless you populate a QS value and check for it on init and then populate the control there?

Comment: normally onInit event is responsible for creating dynamically generated controls. when user click, it post back. again i think you can still use Oninit even in case of click using Page.isPosBack or other way.

Comment: Try using the Viewstate if querystring doesn't work. So, on click populate a value in the Viewstate, check for it in the OnInit method and populate the control from there.

Comment: Is onInit the only way this will work? Will loading everything into panels which I can show and hide be more effective? My only concern with that is I have 152 questions.

Comment: You could try using ajax to capture each answer and update the question. Jquery in combination with a handler file would do that, would mean your code would be a lot neater.

Comment: i tested, if you try to load control on click event, control loaded but not data loaded from database. if you use same code on OnInit even then everything loaded fine. Need small adjustments.